# Use string in subprocess

Tags: python-3.4

I've written Python code to compute an IP  programmatically, that I then want to use in an external connection program.

I don't know how to pass it to the subprocess:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

some_ip = "192.0.2.0"  # Actually the result of some computation,
                       # so I can't just paste it into the call below.

subprocess.call("given.exe -connect  host (some_ip)::5631 -Password")
```

I've read what I could and found similar questions but I truly cannot understand this step, to use the value of `some_ip` in the subprocess. If someone could explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited both the question and my answer. As my previous comments were now obsolete, I've deleted them. Feel free to delete your comments, too. (They might be confusing without context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use it with `shell=True` (and I don't recommend `shell=True` unless you really know what you're doing, as shell mode can have security implications) `subprocess.call` takes the command as an sequence (e.g. a `list`) of its components: First the executable name, then the arguments you want to pass to it. All of those should be strings, but whether they are string literals, variables holding a string or function calls returning a string doesn't matter.

Thus, the following should work:

```
import subprocess

some_ip = "192.0.2.0"  # Actually the result of some computation.

subprocess.call(
    ["given.exe", "-connect",  "host", "{}::5631".format(some_ip), "-Password"])
```

- I'm using [`str`'s `format` method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to replace the `{}` placeholder in `"{}::5631"` with the string in `some_ip`.
- If you invoke it as `subprocess.call(...)`, then

  ```
  import subprocess
  ```

  is sufficient and

  ```
  from subprocess import call
  ```

  is unnecessary. The latter would be needed if you want to invoke the function as just `call(...)`. In that case the former import would be unneeded.

Comment: I may have speak too soon,I tried the code at work (access to VPN) and I've been unable to do the same for the password, if I put it before the IP, it isn't used and after it is used as the host. I noticed that the last time you posted something about the password but then the comments were deleted. Would you be so kind to help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.